# confusion regarding menu inflater and object properties in general

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu

Example:

```
public int testing(){
    return 1;
}

public void main(){
    int getnum = testing();
}
```

`int getnum = testing();` basically calls the testing method and it returns 1 and asigns the value of 1 to the variable getnum which is of type int.

Does this same logic also apply to the following code in eclipse?:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

So does this basically do the same thing as the code at the top? does it create an object of type MenuInflater called inflater and then calls getMenuInflater method which returns an object of type MenuInflater?  as i understand it, this code is equivalent to the following `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,menu);` so `inflater` is now `getMenuInflater()`? I don't understand. Any help would be much appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Yes, your suppositions are correct. So, you understood.

Comment: how can `inflater = getMenuInflater();`? I thought inflater was just asinged a MenuInflater object from the getMenuInflater() method.

Comment: Yes, right. What's the matter? getMenuInflater() is an Android intrinsic method, you don't see it declared in code.